# Delivered Status in Status Callback MMS not working

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

it seems like the status `delivered` is not available for MMS. I get the `sent` status in my callback for a MMS just fine, but not delivered. Why? I use node.

My call looks like this :

```
var sms = { 
    to, 
    from, 
    body: message.message, 
    statusCallback: 'callbackurl',
    mediaUrl: [
     'imageurl1',
     'imageurl2',
   ]
}

clientTwilio.messages.create(sms)
.then((sms) => {
});
```

I receive the MMS as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When Twilio alerts you of the status of the message, it does so using the data it gets back from the network you send the message with. [If the delivery information is not available, Twilio can only mark the message as sent](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133467-Why-are-my-messages-status-sent-).

Comment: Why would the delivery information be unavailable if it works for SMS? It's just not working with MMS. What can I do about this?

Comment: The best way to follow up with this is to contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and give them some message SIDs so they can see why the delivery information wasn't available.